# Automate moving a Chrome window opened by Selenium to a third monitor in Mac OS

Tags: node.js, macos, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to automate the process of setting up a Chrome window opened by Selenium under node.js for some testing, and one requirement is that the window must appear on a different monitor.

It does not seem that Selenium supports this.  I also could not find any other automation apps usable from node.js that support this. I looked at node-window-manager and it does not appear to have any way of moving a window to a different monitor.  It has the ability to see which monitor a window is on, but only under Windows.  I looked at RobotJS, but it does not have multi-monitor support although there are forks which appear to, although as this does not provide a method to simply move a window to a different desktop.

I came upon the idea to simply use AppleScript to invoke the menu option Window > "Move to <monitor model> (2)" but to do this I need to know the process.  Selenium does not support finding the PID of the Chrome process just started, so I am trying to get this from AppleScript.  Unfortunately, there are other Chrome windows open (not related to Selenium) that are open so I can't just look for the Chrome process. So I started with this code to try to locate the window by title:

```
tell application "System Events"
    set allProcesses to application processes
    repeat with i from 1 to count allProcesses
        set thisProcess to item i of allProcesses
        set allWindows to windows of thisProcess
        repeat with j from 1 to count allWindows
            set thisWindow to item j of allWindows
            if name of thisWindow contains "<my window title>"
                tell thisProcess
                    click menu item "Move to <monitor model> (2)" of menu "Window" of menu bar 1
                end tell
                exit repeat
            ...
```

The first time I ran this I got a permissions error and had to grant permissions through the OS. But after this I did not get this error.

However this did not do anything.  I instead tried printing out all the window titles and found a couple of titles that were blank but none that matched my window title.  Thinking to identify the window by size and position, I modified the creation of the Chrome window in Selenium to include the following:

```
let options = new chrome.Options()
options.addArguments("--window-position=0,0")
options.addArguments("--window-size=1000,900")
options.addArguments("--window-name=SELENIUM")
let driver = await new Builder().forBrowser("chrome").setChromeOptions(options).build()
```

However, none of the window titles, sizes, or positions matched.  I noticed that one of the empty named windows disappeared when I closed the Chrome browser opened by Selenium.  So I tried clicking the menu on it.  But this generates an error:

```
Error: System Events got an error: Can’t get menu item "Move to <monitor model> (2)" of menu "Window" of menu bar 1 of application process "Google Chrome"., number: -1728
```

But this window is suspect. It has a very strange size (13x1440) and position (0,-484) which is identical to another reported window.  The second window goes away if I close the unrelated Chrome window.  So I suspect that Chrome always has an offscreen invisible window for some reason, or appears to to AppleScript.

How can I automate moving the Chrome window to a different monitor from node.js under MacOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned, with the robotjs library, you can achieve the desired action by simulating keyboard shortcuts. like (in windows) pressing the combination of 'Windows key + Right arrow key' twice can be used to move a window to the right monitor.

> I looked at RobotJS, but it does not have multi-monitor support although there are forks which appear to, although as this does not provide a method to simply move a window to a different desktop.

Comment: ah that's an interesting idea, assuming i can come up with a specific sequence of keystrokes that will always invoke the correct menu option.  in Mac OS this may be harder than in Windows as there is no accelerator key for "move to window" and i'm not entirely sure it won't break and do something wrong if the menu position changes (which it will if the window for example unexpectedly opens on a different monitor)

Answer (score 0):

For completeness I am posting my own answer which is based on the accepted answer by @dakley which got me started down the right track.

First, I ran this command in my module directory:

```
npm install robotjs
```

Then I added this to my code:

```
const robot = require("robotjs")

...
// driver now created
robot.keyTap("n",["control","alt","command"]);
```

Note that I had to use "alt" instead of "option".  The [robotjs documentation](https://robotjs.io/docs/syntax) mentions alt and not option so I was able to figure this out by the process of elimination when "option" gave me the error "Invalid key flag specified".  For some reason the keyTap function says command is for Windows but it also worked for me on Mac.

Now for a more full explanation of some of the difficulties.

First, it is not sufficient to just blindly send keystrokes, because the menu option to "Move to <device name> (2)" is not guaranteed to always be in the same spot or even present.  There is not any feedback of whether or not each keystroke is accepted.  So I set up a keyboard shortcut specifically to invoke the menu option by going to Apple > System Settings > Keyboard > Keyboard Shortcuts > App Shortcuts > “+” and then entering the exact text of the "Move to..." menu item.  I tried F3 as this did not seem to be in use by anything.  But I found that this did not initially work, and after some troubleshooting I discovered it was because I had Selenium opening Chrome with the developer tools open, and this was capturing my keystroke even though it wasn't doing anything with it.  I changed it to Ctrl+Option+Cmd+N and found that this worked.

Due to the possibility of the UI showing animation, I also added a 2000ms delay after issuing the tap to make sure the animation had finished before continuing.  (1000ms seems to be enough but I wanted some margin)

```
await new Promise(
    (resolve,reject)=>{
        setTimeout(()=>{ resolve() },2000)
    });
```

Edit: Also note that you can't target keyboard input to a specific window with RobotJS so if you try to work in another window when it is working like you can do in Selenium it will cause issues.